# htaccess remove rule line after a specific time

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove an rewrite rule after four hours from the date of manufacture, for example:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^::1 #time of manufacture is 03:03-04-03-2016
RewriteRule ^test/test$ test/index.php [QSA,L]
```

So I expect to that rule to be removed in `03:07-04-03-2016`.

Can that be done by htaccess itself or I need to associate it to SQL database?

Comment: Might be able to set up a conditional using `RewriteCond %{TIME}` - see : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html and http://codeinthehole.com/writing/date-conditional-redirects-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: That was nice but after the timer done how to delete the line :(

Comment: You'd probably have to do it manually; what you'd actually be doing is setting up a rewrite that's only live for the next 4 hours. After which it would stop working - though it would still be in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Or maybe I can use PHP and server corn job

Comment: Maybe - though I'm not 100% certain what you mean by "time of manufacture" ... is that the time the rewrite rule is being created? With a cron job you'd be running a script at a given interval so you could be looping it every 10 minutes or so and cleaning up anything that's older than 4 hours...

Comment: Yes, It's the time of creation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're creating a rewrite rule and you only want it to be live for the next 4 hours you could enter a condition that the rule is less than 4 hours old by entering a `YmdHis` timestamp for *now +4 hours* and adding that as a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^::1
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20160304161800
RewriteRule ^test/test$ test/index.php [QSA,L]
```

In that instance the `RewriteRule` will only trigger until *2016-03-04 16:18:00* after which time the condition will no longer be valid and it'll stop redirecting.

Comment: I think .htaccess have different time type that's why its not working I can't use php's time in :(

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, it's a timestamp in the form `Ymdhis` - updated

Comment: But how to convert php "time()" to this

Comment: With something like `date('YmdHis', strtotime('+4 hours'))`

Comment: wired that its not working :O I think its something with timezone

Comment: Thanks any way for ur help :)

Comment: Odd - that should work; note though that it's an uppercase **H** for hours if you're generating that value from a PHP `date('YmdHis', ... )` function, I mucked it up first time around and entered the lowercase **h** and was momentarily confused by my script telling me it was 02:46 (am)! Lowercase **h** is a 12 hour clock :)